# Story by Stanislaw Lem: the more distinguished you are, the shorter is your name

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, stanislaw-lem

I'm trying to track down a story by Stanislaw Lem for my father. He thought it was titled "Citizen O", but there appears to be no such story. It's about a world in which the more distinguished you are, the shorter is your name. That's all I know, unfortunately.

Comment: No such story appears on the Internet Scifi database; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=citizen&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: Citizen O was a Russian serial killer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Onoprienko

Comment: There's a story in which two officials compete for the favor of the heir to the throne by making themselves smaller and smaller; perhaps your father is thinking about that one?

Comment: The idea rings a bell. I'm not sure that whatever I'm thinking about is Lem though.

Comment: In case of misremembering: In the 1965 novel 'Epp' by Axel Jensen, the opposite is the case. You earn extra letters to your name.

Comment: Thanks all! I really appreciate the responses. Fruitbat, if you figure out which bell it rings, please let me know. Kreiri, I don't think so, but which story is that? And Abulafia, the little that he does remember is exactly the unusualness of it - that the higher up you go un society, the shorter your name gets. Thanks, though.

Comment: Certainly not the answer, but the notion gets re-used in the Ian Banks novel *[Against a Dark Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_a_Dark_Background)*.

Comment: I think it must be _Against a Dark Background_ that I was thinking of.

Comment: In _The Space Merchants_ an important part of the story turns on the fact that the _less_ important you are, the longer your Social Security Number  (tattoed on your arm) is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is from Lem's '[The Star Diaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Diaries), right at the beginning of the Thirteenth Voyage. It was ***"Master Oh"***, not "Citizen O".

> [...] one of the most distinguished individuals in our Universe, Master Oh. [...] Children born on Fatamiasma recieve an enormous number of titles and distinctions as well as a name that is, by our standards, inordinately long.
>
> The day Master Oh came into the world he was called Hridipidagnittusuoayomojorfnagrolliskipwikabeccopyxlbepurz. And duly dubbed Golden Buttress of Being, Doctor of Quintessential Benignity, Most Possibilistive Universatilitude, etc, etc. From year to year, as he studied and matured, the titles and syllables of his name were one by one removed, and since he gave evidence of uncommon abilities, by the thirty-third year of his life he was relieved of his last distinction, and two years later carried no title whatever, while his name was designated in the Fatamiasman alphabet by a single and - morover - voiceless letter, signifying "celestial aspirate" - this is a kind of stifled gasp which one gives from a surfeit of awe and rapture.

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much! This has been driving him mad, and will be a really nice surprise for his 70th birthday.

Comment: @Tal - You can accept the answer if you wish by clicking the checkmark, since it is correct.